# Converting NumPy array into Python List structure

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

How do I convert numpy array, to a Python list? for example

`y = array([[0],[0],[1],[0],[0]])`

`y_list = [0,0,1,0,0]`

i have tried `y.tolist()` and the output: `y=[[0],[0],[1],[0],[0]]`

Comment: What have you tried, and how was it deficient?

Comment: Your NumPy array isn't correct. The conversion to lost works just fine, your array is 2D though and therefore, so is your list.

Comment: `y.tolist()` but the output isn't what I expected

Comment: Why is the array shaped (5,1)?  Is that intentional?  necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) and [`tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
y.ravel().tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatten()` to flatten an array - `array([[1,2], [3,4]])` to `array([1,2,3,4])` and then convert the resulting `array` into `list` using `list()` function.

```
y_list = list(y.flatten('F'))
```